# What does "URL=" in a URL Mean?

Tags: url, iframe

May be a dumb question, but it's been bugging me recently. I see "URL=" inside alot of URL's, such as this one:

http://www.tierraantigua.com/search-2?**url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.flexmls.com%2Fwws30ham**

What exactly is this used to do? Is it part of the iFrame functionality? I know the last part of the URL (after the URL=) is the part being displayed in the iFrame, but I'm unsure of why it is included in the primary URL as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` you see here is just a standard query parameter wit the name `url` and the encoded value `http%3A%2F%2Flink.flexmls.com%2Fwws30ham` which decodes to `http://link.flexmls.com/Fwws30ham`.  Most of the times it is used for determining redirection or source information by the application you are using.  It is entirely domain-specific and can have any meaning the website developer would like to use.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! 

So in this case, the developer is most likely passing that part of the URL into the iFrame so the iFrame can display the parameters from the search forms on other pages.

Comment: I would say that's a reasonable assertion

Answer (score 1):

[PHP GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

**Description ¶**

*An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.*

$url = $_GET['url'];

```
echo $url; // http%3A%2F%2Flink.flexmls.com%2Fwws30ham
```